# sql statement not giving desired results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called results containing about 600 records from previous sports results. Columns include hometeam, awayteam, hometeamscore, awayteamscore etc.

[image]

Im trying to run a query on the table to return results for a specific team for both home and away fixtures.

I do this like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `hometeam` || `awayteam` = "Sharks"
```

The problem is the above query **only returns results for team Sharks when they played away** matches. 
As you can see in the image below:

[image]

**Im looking for a way where I can return both home and away matches** If anyone can point me in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answers below should solve your problem, but I wanted to add that really you should store your teams in a separate table. :)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I was also fixing the same thing, but if my primary goal is to only retrieve results, is it still necessary - and want benefits will it bring to my DB structure...Thanks

Comment: SELECT * FROM results WHERE hometeam = "Sharks" || awayteam = "Sharks"

Comment: @user2955598 it adds flexibility. What if you want to change the team names in future, perhaps to add their town? What if you want to add team information and link them to a team? If they're just fields in a results table, you're going to have problems. In their own table, it's a doddle.

Comment: The query you originally wrote is equivalent to querying `SELECT * FROM results WHERE hometeam = TRUE || awayteam = "Sharks"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't couple your conditions like that. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `hometeam` = "Sharks" || `awayteam` = "Sharks"
```

Comment: Well actually you `CAN` couple conditions like that, it is just so that `hometeam` is being treated as a boolean value :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `hometeam`= "Sharks" || `awayteam` = "Sharks"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE (`hometeam` = "Sharks") || (`awayteam` = "Sharks")
```